# How to set the default value for a varargs parameter in scala?

Tags: scala

If I have a varargs parameter of type `Enum`, can I set a default value for this parameter?

```
def functionName(parameter: Enum* = defaultValue)
```

What should I do for the `defaultValue` above?

Comment: thanks everyone, I know there's work around. I just want to know whether I can do this by default. problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't:

> a parameter section with a `*'-parameter is not allowed to have default arguments

Comment: Please add the source for this statement.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/ContextErrors.scala#L286) seems like a reliable source :-).

Answer (score 2):

As this has already been mentioned you can't do it directly so you have to hack around. This is also not an ideal solution but you might like this hack better than the other choices:

```
def functionName(): Int = functionName(1, 2, 3)

def functionName(parameter: Int*): Int = parameter.sum
```

and `println(functionName())` obviously prints `6`

Comment: Won't compile for me.

Comment: @jwvh, which compiler do you use? It seems to work for me just fine using both Scala 2.11.8 and 2.12.4

Comment: You're right. It fails both my REPL and IntelliJ worksheet attempts, but no problems when compiled from a file. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

You can't since passing 0 arguments is also valid for a varargs parameter. But you can simply put a check in the method body.

```
def functionName(parameter: Enum*) = {
  val parameter0 = if (parameter.nonEmpty) parameter else Seq(defaultValue)
  ???
}
```